# Python interrupt process signal/threading

Tags: python, asynchronous, subprocess, interrupt

I am looking for the best solution to kill an external process that is ran through my python code when a file is created.
I tried this naive code:

```
import os
import time

def test_function():
   bool = True
   # TODO CHECK ONLINE IF THE RUN HAS TO BE TERMINATED
   if content_on_web_page == "an example":
      bool = False
      os.system("touch STOP")
   return bool
def run():
    os.system("myexternalprogram") # program that takes time to run but stops if "STOP" file is in the directory

while test_function():
    run()
```

This code does not work because python should check at a certain rate that the file is not existing
I have checked solutions and it seems there are possibilities around threading/signal/asyncio, but I am wondering what is the best fit in my case.
Any help ? Thanks

Comment: So do you control the external process, and can make it check for the file? Or do you just start the external process and need to kill it? It's hard to tell when your example doesn't have any subprocess at all ...

Comment: Actually the file is just an example. In my case I would actually need to look at an online page status at a certain rate (say each 5 seconds) while my "run()" function is running.

Comment: OK, but the question stands. Can you change the process to check the condition directly, or do you have to check the condition in a separate process?

Comment: No, I cant change the process.

Comment: OK, so you've started some external process whose inner workings are out of your control. What options you have to stop it depend slightly on how you started it: for example [`subprocess.Popen.terminate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). So, how do you start this process, and what happens when you try telling it to terminate?

Comment: I have a way to stop it, for example creating a "stop" file that the external program will read. The thing is, to create this file automatically within the python script, i need to check the content of a web page at a certain rate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240183/discussion-between-useless-and-carlitador).